# Unexpected Template deduction

Tags: c++, templates

```
template< typename T >
void addVarCB(const std::string &name,
              TwSetVarCallback setCallback, TwGetVarCallback getCallback,
              void * clientData, const std::string &def = "" );

template< class C, typename T >
void addVarCB(const std::string &name,
              C * _this, T(C::*getter)(void), const std::string &def = "");
```

The following code will compile and crash on runtime:

```
bar_->addVarCB<MyClass, unsigned>("foo", this, &MyClass::MyClassFn, nullptr);
```

I would actually expect it NOT to compile at all, as there is no function that takes its parameters as an argument! (note that "MyClass, unsigned" is unnecessary but just to be clear...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sadly, `std::string` is constructible from `nullptr`, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), specifically `(5)`:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s, // <== 'nullptr' matches here
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Note:

> 5) Constructs the string with the contents of null-terminated character string pointed to by `s`. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. **`s` must not be a `NULL` pointer.**

Answer (score 5):

The first comment is that this is unrelated to template deduction. Because you are providing the template arguments, no deduction is ever used and the second template is used.

The function call compiles as there is a conversion from `nullptr` to `const char*` that can be used to call the `std::string` constructor that takes a `const char*`. The contract of that constructor requires that the pointer is valid and points to a null terminated sequence of characters which is false in your code.